# Date Picker is not disabling dates

Tags: datepicker

I need to disable the first and third Wednesday in each month. The code I am using is below.This was working but when I added the new dates for 2021 it stopped working. Please help. Thanks

```
 <script>
    var dates = ["6-3-2019","20-3-2019","3-4-2019","17-4-2019","1-5-2019","15-5-2019","5-6-2019","19-6-2019","3-7-2019","17-7-2019","7-8-2019","21-8-2019","4-9-2019","18-9-2019","2-10-2019","16-10-2019","6-11-2019","20-11-2019","4-12-2019","18-12-2019","1-1-2020","15-1-2020","5-2-2020","19-2-2020","4-3-2020","18-3-2020","1-4-2020","15-4-2020","6-5-2020","20-5-2020","3-6-2020","17-6-2020","1-7-2020","15-7-2020","5-8-2020","19-8-2020","2-9-2020","16-9-2020","7-10-2020","21-10-2020","4-11-2020","18-11-2020","2-12-2020","16-12-2020","06-01-2021","20-01-2021","03-02-2021","17-02-2021","03-03-2021","17-03-2021","07-04-2021","21-04-2021","05-05-2021","19-05-2021","02-06-2021","16-06-2021","07-07-2021","21-07-2021","04-08-2021","18-08-2021","01-09-2021","15-09-2021","06-10-2021","20-10-2021","03-11-2021","17-11-2021","01-12-2021","15-12-2021"];
    
    function DisableDates(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
        return [dates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
    
    $(function() {
         $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
             beforeShowDay: DisableDates,
             minDate: +1
             
         });
        
        });
          </script>
```

Comment: The above code shows date format for 2021 as 06-01-2021 but I had also tried using date format 6-1-2021